# How to open incognito/private window with Selenium WD for different browser types?

Tags: java, browser, selenium-webdriver

I want to test my test cases in ***private window*** or ***incognito window***.

How to do the same in various browsers:

- firefox (prefered)
- chrome (prefered)
- IE
- safari
- opera

***How to achieve it?***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run chrome browser in inconginto Mode in Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026295/run-chrome-browser-in-inconginto-mode-in-selenium)

Answer (score 26):

- Chrome:

  ```
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("incognito");
  capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
  ```
- FireFox:

  ```
  FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();    
  firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", true);
  ```
- Internet Explorer:

  ```
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
  capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS, true); 
  capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_SWITCHES, "-private");
  ```
- Opera:

  ```
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.operaBlink();
  OperaOptions options = new OperaOptions();
  options.addArguments("private");
  capabilities.setCapability(OperaOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
  ```

Comment: For future visitor- this does not work with selenium 2.53, works with 2.52.

Comment: Which points don't work? We use Selenium 3.0.1 and everything works correctly.

Comment: Yes it works with 3.0.1, Sadly I am not able(read allowed) to upgrade to the latest version. I've wasted more than 2 hours So i thought it might be beneficial for someone facing same issue.

Comment: The above code for Firefox, is not working in my case

Answer (score 16):

In chrome you can try using `-incognito` command line switch in options, not sure if there will be a problem with automation extension but worth a try.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("incognito");
```

For FireFox, a special flag in the profile can be used for the purpose

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();    
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.private.browsing.autostart",true);
```

For IE

```
setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_SWITCHES, "-private");
```

Comment: The above code for firefox is not working in my case.

Answer (score 4):

```
FirefoxOptions opts = new FirefoxOptions();
opts.addArguments("-private");
FirefoxDrive f = new FirefoxDriver(opts);
```

This works fine for selenium version 3.14.0 and geckodriver-v0.22.0

Answer (score 1):

```
public class gettext {
  static WebDriver driver= null;

  public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

    //for private window

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
    option.addArguments("incognito");
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,option);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Tools\\chromedriver.exe");       
    driver= new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

    String url = "https://www.google.com/";
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    gettextdata();
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the body element on the page and then fire off a Key Chord to it for the browser you want.  In the sample below I've tried to abstract the browsers to an enumeration that outline the behavior for *newTab*, *newWindow* and *newIncognitoWindow*.  I made content FF, IE, Chrome, Safari, and Opera; however, they may not be fully implemented due to my lack of knowledge.

```
  /**
     * Enumeration quantifying some common keystrokes for Browser Interactions.
     * 
     * @see "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33224070/how-to-open-incognito-private-window-through-selenium-java"
     * @author http://stackoverflow.com/users/5407189/jeremiah
     * @since Oct 19, 2015
     *
     */
    public static enum KeystrokeSupport {
        CHROME,
        FIREFOX {
            @Override
            protected CharSequence getNewIncognitoWindowCommand() {
                return Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SHIFT, "p");
            }
        },
        IE {
            @Override
            protected CharSequence getNewIncognitoWindowCommand() {
                return Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SHIFT, "p");
            }
        },
        SAFARI {
            @Override
            protected CharSequence getNewTabCommand() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Author does not know this keystroke");
            }

            @Override
            protected CharSequence getNewWindowCommand() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Author does not know this keystroke");
            }

            @Override
            protected CharSequence getNewIncognitoWindowCommand() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Author does not know this keystroke");
            }
        },
        OPERA {
            @Override
            protected CharSequence getNewIncognitoWindowCommand() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Author does not know this keystroke");
            }
        };

        public final void newTab(WebDriver driver) {
            WebElement target = getKeystrokeTarget(driver);
            target.sendKeys(getNewTabCommand());
        }

        public final void newWindow(WebDriver driver) {
            WebElement target = getKeystrokeTarget(driver);
            target.sendKeys(getNewWindowCommand());
        }

        public final void newIncognitoWindow(WebDriver driver) {
            WebElement target = getKeystrokeTarget(driver);
            target.sendKeys(getNewIncognitoWindowCommand());
        }

        protected CharSequence getNewTabCommand() {
            return Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "t");
        }

        protected CharSequence getNewWindowCommand() {
            return Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "n");
        }

        protected CharSequence getNewIncognitoWindowCommand() {
            return Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SHIFT, "t");
        }

        protected final WebElement getKeystrokeTarget(WebDriver driver) {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("body")));
        }

    }
```

With that then, we can offer a Parameterized test that will run through each of the configurations and execute the behaviors for **visual verification**.  You may want to add whatever asserts you want to the test.

```
package stackoverflow.proof.selenium;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


import com.google.common.base.Supplier;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;



/**
 * Test to try out some various browser keystrokes and try to get the environment to do what we want.
 * 
 * @see "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33224070/how-to-open-incognito-private-window-through-selenium-java"
 * @author http://stackoverflow.com/users/5407189/jeremiah
 * @since Oct 19, 2015
 *
 */
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class KeyStrokeTests {


    @Parameters(name="{0}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> buildTestParams() {
        Collection<Object[]> params = Lists.newArrayList();
        Supplier<WebDriver> ffS = new Supplier<WebDriver>() {
            public WebDriver get() {
                return new FirefoxDriver();
            }
        };
        params.add(new Object[]{KeystrokeSupport.FIREFOX, ffS});

      /* I'm not currently using these browsers, but this should work with minimal effort.
        Supplier<WebDriver> chrome = new Supplier<WebDriver>() {
            public WebDriver get() {
                return new ChromeDriver();
            }
        };
        Supplier<WebDriver> ie = new Supplier<WebDriver>() {
            public WebDriver get() {
                return new InternetExplorerDriver();
            }
        };
        Supplier<WebDriver> safari = new Supplier<WebDriver>() {
            public WebDriver get() {
                return new SafariDriver();
            }
        };
        Supplier<WebDriver> opera = new Supplier<WebDriver>() {
            public WebDriver get() {
                return new OperaDriver();
            }
        };

        params.add(new Object[]{KeystrokeSupport.CHROME, chrome});
        params.add(new Object[]{KeystrokeSupport.IE, ie});
        params.add(new Object[]{KeystrokeSupport.SAFARI, safari});
        params.add(new Object[]{KeystrokeSupport.OPERA, opera});
        */
        return params;
    }
    Supplier<WebDriver> supplier;
    WebDriver driver;
    KeystrokeSupport support;

    public KeyStrokeTests(KeystrokeSupport support,Supplier<WebDriver> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
        this.support = support;
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        driver = supplier.get();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void testNewTab() {
        support.newTab(driver);
    }
    @Test
    public void testNewIncognitoWindow() {
        support.newIncognitoWindow(driver);
    }

    @Test
    public void testNewWindow() {
        support.newWindow(driver);
    }

    @After
    public void lookAtMe() throws Exception{
        Thread.sleep(5000);    
          for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            driver.close();
        }
    }
  }
```

Best of Luck.

Comment: I hate seing ideas, that could possibly work, but with few minus votes and no comments what is wrong with this one.

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome use this code to open the browser in incognito mode:

```
public WebDriver chromedriver;
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("-incognito");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver chromedriver=new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
chromedriver.get("url");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void OpenBrowser() {
    if (Browser.equals("Chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Workspace\\proj\\chromedriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("incognito");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    } else if (Browser.equals("IE")) {

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS, false);
// if you get this exception "org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: " . uncomment the below line and comment the above line
// capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS, true);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "E:\\Workspace\\proj\\IEDriverServer32.exe");capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_SWITCHES, "-private");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
    } else {
        FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", true);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run remote IE in private mode only after following updates:

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions()
                    .ignoreZoomSettings()
                    .useCreateProcessApiToLaunchIe()
                    .addCommandSwitches("-private");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
            capabilities.setCapability("se:ieOptions", options);
return new RemoteWebDriver(url, capabilities);
```

All of above didn't work for RemoteWebDriver.

Answer (score 0):

How to avoid Extensions in Private Mode prompt

For the actual geckodriver version I use:

```
    options.addArguments("-private");
```

It works fine but the annoying notification appears: Extensions in Private Mode.

I found the way to avoid it:

```
    options.addPreference("extensions.allowPrivateBrowsingByDefault",true);
```

As a result all extensions will run in private browsing mode without prompting at start

Answer (score 0):

For other browser everyone has answered
so for OPERA

```
OperaOptions options = new OperaOptions();
options.addArguments("private");
WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver(options);
driver.get("https://selenium.dev");
```