# How to set browser window size for Chrome and Opera launched by Selenium WebDriver in incognito/private mode?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on application which will execute tests on multiple browser types (Chrome, FireFox, Internet Explorer and Opera). I found the way how to launched them in incognito/private modes ([How to open incognito/private window with Selenium WD for different browser types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33224070/4944847)) and set window size ([Browser window control #174](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/174)):

```
Window window = driver.manage().window();
window.setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
window.setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

But this code does not work in all cases:

```
+-------------------+----------+-------------------+
|      Browser      | Standard | Incognito/Private |
|-------------------|----------|-------------------|
|      Chrome       |  works   |   does not work   |
|-------------------|----------|-------------------|
|      FireFox      |  works   |       works       |
|-------------------|----------|-------------------|
| Internet Explorer |  works   |       works       |
|-------------------|----------|-------------------|
|      Opera        |  works   |   does not work   |
+-------------------+----------+-------------------+
```

How to solve this problem? I know that I can pass arguments to drivers using `ChromeOptions` and `OperaOptions`. But I would like to change size during tests executions. It will be great if I don't need to eval JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The are some problems with automation testing in Chrome and Opera browsers.

Issues:

- Chrome:

  - [Chrome automation extension isn't allowed in incognito mode](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=513)
  - [Selenium cannot use Window() functions when in incognito mode](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1350)
- Opera:

  - [driver.manage().window().setSize does not work in private mode](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/issues/22)

I temporary solved them using the code:

- Chrome

  ```
  ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
  driver.get("chrome://extensions-frame");
  WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class='incognito-control']/input[@type='checkbox']"));
  if (!checkbox.isSelected()) {
      checkbox.click();
  }
  ```
- Opera:

  ```
  OperaDriver driver = new OperaDriver(capabilities);
  driver.get("chrome://extensions");
  WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'incognito-control')]/label/input[@type='checkbox']"));
  if (!checkbox.isSelected()) {
      checkbox.click();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Hi in Google chrome (incog mode) i think re-sizing is not possible.re-sizing in normal instance of google chrome is possible but not with incog mode on.with doing more research i closely observed the error shown in eclipse (incog mode on)

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: No current window
JavaScript stack:
Error: No current window
    at checkForExtensionError (chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/background.js:14:17)
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/background.js:67:5)
    at safeCallbackApply (extensions::sendRequest:21:15)
    at handleResponse (extensions::sendRequest:72:7)
  (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.110)
```

you can see at line **checkForExtensionError** you will find that why its not possible.

1.please open chrome://extensions/ in chrome and enable developer option then

2.under **Chrome Automation Extension** you will see the same ID that is shown in the error (posted above).

3. but **allow in incognito** not checked

4.Please open the location of the **manifest.json** under Loaded from: inside that you will find the below contents

```
{
  "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDr+Q7QFcTr4Wmn9sSICKWbxnYLhIM0ERbcapZCDm",
  "name": "Chrome Automation Extension",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Exposes extension APIs for automating Chrome",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
     "tabs", "management", "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

under **description** u can clearly see that

```
"description": "Exposes extension APIs for automating Chrome",
```

Hence if **Point 3** is not enabled it is not possible to automate anything with webdriver in chrome.

Also i do not know how to enable **point 3** via automation if you can then you can surely resize window in incog mode. hope this helps

Comment: Your hint with `Chrome Automation Extension` helps me to solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: thankyou @ agabrys i am very glad that it helped you and also thankyou too you as well as your answer helped me to know how to enable point 3

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative to set the size of the window once the browser is launched:

```
// open a new window to the desired size
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
    "window.open(window.location.href, 'mywindow', 'height=400,width=400');");

// close the current window
driver.close();

// set the context to the new window
driver.switchTo().window("mywindow");

// the new window is now resizeable by JavaScript
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.resizeTo(800,600);");
```

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot do that. I want to add the ability to change the window during the test.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the last line. You will be able to change the size during the test since "window.resizeTo" is no longer restricted for a window created with "window.open".

Comment: I'm not convinced to create a new window and closing the previous one. I found the reported problems (in Chrome and Opera drivers tracking systems) - so I created a temporary code which solved them. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score -3):

Hi we can set the size of the browser using the dimension class.The dimension class provides the method called .using it we can do .
Example for setting the size of  is :

```
    Dimension d = new Dimension(420,600);
    //Resize the current window to the given dimension
    driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
```

Comment: Please read question again. I used this code but id does not work.