# How to maximise the window in chrome browser in incognito mode using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium

How to maximise the window in chrome browser in incognito mode using Selenium WebDriver

I am using the below code:

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--incognito");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities =  DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

But in the last line code I am getting error as **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: No current window**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36352668/6929467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maximize the Chrome Browser in incognito mode you need to use the ChromeOptions class as follows:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--incognito");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: How do you get ChromeOptions in Typescript?