# selenium firefox driver private mode not working

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I've been searching a lot and found lots of answers but none of them working. I want to start a Firefox Webdriver in private mode.

I have Firefox version 54 installed and gecko driver v0.18.
Selenium v3.4.0

I use the following code:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.EnableNativeEvents = true;
profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
profile.AssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer = true;
profile.SetPreference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", true);
profile.SetPreference("browser.privatebrowsing.dont_prompt_on_enter", true);
//profile.SetPreference("browser.startup.homepage", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartURL"]);

FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.Profile = profile;
//options.AddArgument("--private");

FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(DRIVER_PATH);
webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15000));

var screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
var screenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
webDriver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(screenWidth, screenHeight);

webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartURL"]);

//from firefox 55 can maximize again. Wait for update.
//webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

I also noticed that when I debug during a test and press CTRL+SHIFT+P a new "private" window opens but I do NOT see the private glasses icon. What is wrong? Is this a bug?

Comment: Which Selenium version do you use?

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36332841/1318411

Comment: editted my question, using selenium webdriver v3.4.0

Comment: @sen4ik thanks but I've allready seen this page.