# Why do I get Syntax error on token for ChromeOptions

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

This is code with the error.
IDE: Eclipse

[image]

---

**EDIT:** I used `addArguments` but the error still there,

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run chrome browser in inconginto Mode in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026295/run-chrome-browser-in-inconginto-mode-in-selenium)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Mohsen_Fatemi the issue is still happening

Comment: Your code is outside of a method. You cannot have statement like this outside of a method, constructor or (static) initializer.

Comment: LOL I just realized that, sorry for the stupid situation, thank you:
EDIT: Can I choose your answer as the correct one? well this is a comment....so

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html#addArguments-java.lang.String...-), the method name should be `addArguments` not `AddArgument`. By the way, Java uses camelCase for methods by convention. The code you currently have is a correct C# code, so it seems that you've copied a C# snippet from somewhere.

If the error still exists, try clean & rebuilding the project or restarting the IDE and/or your PC. It might be that "Eclipse" just have some weird problem.

Comment: please check udpated picture, that is not the issue

Comment: @notPercival Check the updated answer.

Comment: Just did that, not working still

Comment: @notPercival Are you sure you did a clean before building? Have you tried another IDE? The code looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the name of the function incorrectly, it is `options.addArguments("--incognito");`

Comment: that is how everybody uses it in examples