# Disable cache on network tab using python selenium(automation)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-devtools

I need to disable cache on network tab using selenium python . tried below ways but nothing worked

```
   options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            options.add_argument("--incognito")
            options.add_argument('--disable-application-cache')
            options.add_argument("--disk-cache-size=0")
            options.add_argument("--disk-cache-dir=/dev/null")
            options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
            d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
            d['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL'}
```

- Tried to open URL incognito mode but still I have to open devtools and disable cache manually

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026295/run-chrome-browser-in-inconginto-mode-in-selenium/19026738

Answer (score 4):

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.setCacheDisabled", {"cacheDisabled":True})
```

use chrome dev protocol , see if this helps

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setCacheDisabled